# Are random seeds "spent" in some way?

Tags: r, random

I expected this code to give me the same number each time:

```
set.seed(1)
sample(rep(1:100), size = 1)
```

However, it doesn't. Here's is how it behaves: it gives me the same number if I run the two lines directly after each other, however, if I then run the second line once again, it gives me something different. Does that mean the seed is "spent" after running `sample()` once?

I need to produce code that includes random sampling, but which is reproducible. How can I make sure the same, random number is produced each time?

Comment: I get 27 every time I run those two lines. What do you get?

Comment: Also, why the `rep()`? Without a second argument it's not doing anything.

Comment: Using the same seed typically will give you the same random numbers in most languages.

Comment: Hmm...here's the behavior, it gives me the same number if I run the two lines directly after each other, however, if I then run the second line once again, it gives me something different. Does that mean the seed is "spent" after running `sample()` once?

Comment: That's how seeds work. Setting the seed gets you to a particular point. Any number of random numbers after that will be reproducible if you set the seed again. That is `set.seed(1); sample(1:100, size = 1); sample(1:100, size = 1)` will always yield 27, then 38.

Comment: Can someone explain how I can improve this question? I don't understand the 4 close votes.

Comment: Write some sentences at the top that give a statement of the problem (don't use the title as the statement).

Comment: @histelheim - they are maybe a little harsh - the best/clearest information on your misunderstanding was in your comment above though - incorporate that into the question as it is then of more specific interest and not confusing.

Comment: Agreed, I don't think this question should be closed on the basis stated. It may be a duplicate of similar questions in the past but I think it's worded simply enough and has garnered good responses, it should be open.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not that the seed is spent; rather, setting the seed produces a fixed sequence of pseudo-random values that you'll be sampling from. Once you've sampled one value from the sequence, the next value you sample will be the subsequent value in the sequence. However, if you reset the seed, then you will start back at the beginning of the sequence when you sample again.

Answer (score 15):

This isn't exactly how things really work, but it helps for understanding.

Imagine that we're drawing numbers between 0 and 9 by looking them up in a pre-generated book of random numbers. A really long book with lots and lots of random draws made by some bored undergraduate intern with a fair 10-sided die. What R normally does is look at the number following whatever the previous random number was in the book. So if the book starts `4, 5, 2, 8, 3, 4, 4, 1, 7, 0, 4, ...` the first random number will be 4, then 5 etc.

The results will be as random as the book is---no matter where in the book we start. Typically, you don't know what you're going to get because you have no idea where in the book R is currently at, maybe page 103, maybe page 10003. Setting the seed tells R to start at a specific place. So `set.seed(1)` says "start on page 1", so you now can count on that "4" being first, and then followed by a 5, and so forth.